# how to toggle different divs with javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function toggleB(){
    var b1 = document.getElementById("1");
    var b2 = document.getElementById("2");
    var b3 = document.getElementById("3");
    
    if (b1.style.display === "none"){
        b1.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b1.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (b2.style.display === "none"){
        b2.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b2.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (b3.style.display === "none"){
        b3.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b3.style.display = "block";
    }   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="imgBtns">
        <div id="b1">
           <input onclick="toggleB" type="image" src="/">
            <a href="#">B1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="b2">
            <input onclick="toggleB" type="image" src="/">
            <a href="#">B2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="b3">
            <input onclick="toggleB" type="image" src="/">
            <a href="#">B3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="mainText">
          <p>This should be displayed first without b1,b2,b3 showing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="button1">
            <p>you clicked b1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="button2">
            <p>you clicked b2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="button3">
            <p>you clicked b3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the javascript function to be able toggle between showing divs(b1,b2,b3) by clicking their image button or a tag. Once an img input button or a tag is clicked it should remove the "mainText" and only show the clicked div to the user. The mainText div should be removed and be replaced with the corresponding button div that is clicked.

```js
function toggleB{
    var b1 = document.getElementById("1");
    var b2 = document.getElementById("2");
    var b3 = document.getElementById("3");
    
    if (b1.style.display === "none"){
        b1.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b1.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (b2.style.display === "none"){
        b2.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b2.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (b3.style.display === "none"){
        b3.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b3.style.display = "block";
    }   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="imgBtns">
        <div id="b1">
           <input onclick="toggleB" type="image" src="/">
            <a href="#">B1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="b2">
            <input onclick="toggleB" type="image" src="/">
            <a href="#">B2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="b3">
            <input onclick="toggleB" type="image" src="/">
            <a href="#">B3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="mainText">
          <p>This should be displayed first without b1,b2,b3 showing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="1">
            <p>you clicked b1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="2">
            <p>you clicked b2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="3">
            <p>you clicked b3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function toggleB{
    var b1 = document.getElementById("1");
    var b2 = document.getElementById("2");
    var b3 = document.getElementById("3");
    
    if (b1.style.display === "none"){
        b1.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b1.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (b2.style.display === "none"){
        b2.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b2.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (b3.style.display === "none"){
        b3.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b3.style.display = "block";
    }   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="imgBtns">
        <div id="b1">
           <input onclick="toggleB" type="image" src="/">
            <a href="#">b1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="b2">
            <input onclick="toggleB" type="image" src="/">
            <a href="#">b2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="b3">
            <input onclick="toggleB" type="image" src="/">
            <a href="#">b3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="mainText">
          <p>This should be displayed first without b1,b2,b3 showing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="1">
            <p>b1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="2">
            <p>b2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="3">
            <p>b3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id` cannot start with a `number`. When using `onclick` (which is considered bad practice) the function name must end with parentheses `<input onclick="toggleB()"`

Answer (score 0):

You whole concept is far too complicated.

Instead, put the `id` of the `div` to toggle into a `data-toggles`-Attribute. Then dynamically select that `div` and toggle the `hidden` attribute.

A simplified example:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggles]');

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const toggleDiv = document.getElementById(button.dataset.toggles);
  toggleDiv.toggleAttribute('hidden');
}));
```

```css
.toggle-divs>div[id] {
  background-color: #a00;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.toggle-divs>div[id]::before {
  content: "#"attr(id)" here";
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-buttons">
  <button data-toggles="foo">toggle #foo</button>
  <button data-toggles="bar">toggle #bar</button>
  <button data-toggles="baz">toggle #baz</button>
</div>

<div class="toggle-divs">
  Below here is the toggle divs:
  
  <div id="foo" hidden></div>
  <div id="bar" hidden></div>
  <div id="baz" hidden></div>
</div>
```